# Powershell - OpenFileDialog.FileName and FileBrowserDialog.SelectedFolder return an object instead of a string

Tags: powershell

I am trying to build a Powershell script to convert some audio files in a folder, and I am using a FolderBrowserDialog to ask the user the location of the output folder, and an OpenFileDialog to get the path of the converter program (in case it is not in the same folder of the script).
Both dialogs are called withing separate functions, which are called by the main program.

The problem is that when I return 'OpenFileDialog.FileName' and 'FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath' from each function, I get an object which contains the path and some other values and not the path itself as a string.

This are the objects I get from the functions:
[OpenFileDialog.FileName Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOLvh.png)
[FolderBrowserdialog.SelectedPath Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2bI9.png)

The functions are:

```
Function GetConverterPath
{ 
    $currentDirectory = Split-Path -Parent $PSCommandPath; 
    $isConverterInCurrentDirectory = Test-Path $($currentDirectory + "\tfa2wav.exe")  

    if($isConverterInCurrentDirectory)
    {
        return ($currentDirectory + "\tfa2wav.exe");
    } 


    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("The converter's *.exe file was not found in the same directory as this script`n" + 
                                      "Please, point to the right file in the next dialog...", 'Converter not found...','Ok','Information');

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms');

    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog;
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = 'Executable files (*.exe)|*.exe';
    $result = $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()

    if($result -eq 'OK')
    {
        return $OpenFileDialog.FileName;  
    }
    else
    {
        exit;
    }    
}

Function AskForOutputFolder
{    
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("In the next dialog you should select the folder where the converted sound files will be placed",                                     
                                      'Information','Ok','Information');

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")|Out-Null;

    $folderBrowserDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog;
    $folderBrowserDialog.Description = "Select a folder";
    $result = $folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog()

    if($result -eq 'OK')
    {
        return $folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
    }
    else
    {
        exit;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Also, how can I prevent the 'OK' messages from appearing in the console after each dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`Get-Help 'about_return'`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-7):

> In PowerShell, the **results of each statement are returned as
>   output**, even without a statement that contains the Return keyword.

Use e.g `[System.Void]` struct as follows

```
[void][System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show(…);

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms');
```

As an alternative:

```
$null = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show(…);
```

Another alternative (slowest so avoid using this in loops):

```
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show(…) | Out-Null
```

Comment: That solved the console messages problem, and the problem for the "FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath", but when returning "OpenFileDialog.FileName", I still get an object. In this case, the object no longer contains the 'OK' message, but it is a 'System.Windows.Forms' object which contains the path I need (it is shown in the first link). 

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Never mind, already fixed that. I forgot to put a [System.Void] struct in the line below the messagebox, in both functions. Thanks for your help!